# Small lag/jitter when tapping the screen

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, lag

So my game is almost complete... but there's this little glitch or jitter that occurs when I press and hold my finger on the screen which, now I've noticed, I can't un-notice...

It happens really fast, and only happens when a function is called to handle tap&holds (long press). This happens after 0.2seconds have passed using a timer.

I've tried breakpointing it to pin down where exactly the jitter happens in the code, but it seems I can not fine tune it enough to locate it.

My update method is typical:

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    //calc delta time
    if lastUpdateTime > 0 {
        dt = currentTime - lastUpdateTime
    } else {
        dt = 0
    }
    lastUpdateTime = currentTime

    //timer for handleLongPress
    if touched {
        longTouchTimer += dt
    }

    if longTouchTimer >= 0.2 && !canLongPressNow {
        canLongPressNow = true
        handleLongPress()
    } else {
        canLongPressNow = false
    }

    ...
    //switch GameSate
    //switch CharacterState
}
```

My function to handleLongPress is this:

```
func handleLongPress() {
    //switch gameState
    //if in gameplay gamestate
        if canLongPressNow {
            //rotate player
            //change character state
            startPlayerAnimation_Sliding()
        }
    touched = false
    longTouchTimer = 0
}
```

The `startPlayerAnimation_Sliding()` just iterates a texture array of the playerNode.

```
func startPlayerAnimation_Sliding() {
   var textures: Array<SKTexture> = []
    for i in 0..<KNumSlideFrames{
        textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "slide\(i)"))
    }
    let playerAnimation = SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.3)
    player.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(playerAnimation), withKey: "sliding")
}
```

Is there anything noticeable that may be causing this?

**update**

I've removed this from my `update(..)` method, and it seems smooth again... and I have no idea why...? Maybe because it's removing a key (explosion) that hasn't been created yet? or the fact it's removing these keys every frame... Doesn't make sense though... But I'm calling it a night, and looking at this again tomorrow. Thanks for your help so far. Have a good evening. (will update tomorrow)

```
    //for animations
    switch characterState {
        case .Running:
            player.removeActionForKey("exploding")
            player.removeActionForKey("sliding")
            break
        case .Sliding:
            player.removeActionForKey("running")
            player.removeActionForKey("exploding")
            break
        case .Exploding:
            player.removeActionForKey("running")
            player.removeActionForKey("sliding")
            break
    }
```

Comment: Have you run your app through Instruments to find the heaviest stack trace?

Comment: may I see startPlayerAnimation,  that seems to be the only spot where it could hang

Comment: I did but couldn't notice anything. And I've updated my code above with the function.. It appears to only affect enemy nodes that are moving across the screen that aren't to do with the handle... also there doesn't seem to be a drop in FPS either

Comment: It seems you're loading lots of textures when the long press happens. Is it not possible to cache them?

Comment: Still getting a jitter... it's almost like it's going backwards 1 frame and then continuing.. so strange

Comment: I may have located it... see my updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yikes, how you create textures is what is slowing you down a lot,  you are creating new textures every time a touch happens,  this is not needed.  Instead do:

```
var textures: Array<SKTexture> = []
var playerAnimation : SKAction?
func loadingPhase()  //however this is defined for you
{
    for i in 0..<KNumSlideFrames{
        textures.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "slide\(i)"))
    }
    playerAnimation = SKAction.repeatActionForever(SKAction.animateWithTextures(textures, timePerFrame: 0.3))

}
func startPlayerAnimation_Sliding() {


    player.runAction(playerAnimation!, withKey: "sliding")
}
```

Comment: When handleLongPress() is called, it resets the longTouchTimer, which means it's only loading them once, but once every time it's called, by which time it's started a different animation in between. So it's not called every frame. I could load the textures first though so they're not reloaded everytime the longTouchTimer exceeds the time limit of a tap and hold.

Comment: I meant every time that the touch happens not the frame,  still the process should not be done the way you are doing it,  did you try my method to see if it speeds it up

Comment: Initialised it like this: `var playerAnimation_Sliding = SKAction.self() ` and call a `loading()` function in `didMoveToView()`... seems to be running flawless with much more consistant FPS. Thank you so much :D Maybe you should be making this app not me. :) Ps. What's the `!` for after your runAction(playerAnimation? I don't have it, but it still works...?

Comment: Because i have the variable as optional but i typoed and didnt make it optional in your code,  that is why it was yellig at you. See update declaration

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Is it better to make it optional, or is `SKAction.self()` just as good?

Comment: it depends on how you want it done,  in your case, it makes no difference since we are defining it at init, and it basically becomes a constant,  but sometimes you want the value to be nil,  so you use an optional.  Also,  `SKAction()` works just fine, no need for .self()

Comment: OK thanks. Well for some reason if I remove .self it errors as it `expects member name or constructor call after type name`... so I'm just leaving it. Thanks for your help :D

Comment: that is because you did `var playerAnimation_Sliding = SKAction` not `var playerAnimation_Sliding = SKAction()`